# How to create validation for autosave reactive Angular 2 form.

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I need suggestion on how to create an autosave reactive Angular 2 form. Basically user type in the value, the form is autosave if the value is validated. Here is the code

```
    export class BusinessFoundationsPage {

      businessFoundationsForm: FormGroup;
      userId: string;
      YouTuber: YouTuber;
      loading: any;
      isThisFirstTimeFlag: boolean;
      businessFoundationsKey: string;
      locationId: string;

      constructor(public af: AngularFire, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public fb: FormBuilder, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public userData: UserData) {
        this.locationId = this.navParams.get('locationId');
        this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          content: 'Please wait...'
        });

        this.loading.present();

        this.businessFoundationsForm = this.fb.group({
          businessFoundationsQ1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
          businessFoundationsQ2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
        })

      }

      ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad BusinessFoundationsPage');

        this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
          if (auth) {
            console.log ("Current State: Login");
            this.userId = auth.uid;
            this.userData.getUserDetail(this.userId).subscribe(user => {
              this.YouTuber = user;

              let formControls: any = this.businessFoundationsForm.controls;
              if (this.YouTuber.businessFoundations) {
                this.isThisFirstTimeFlag = false;
                this.userData.getBusinessFoundationsData(this.YouTuber.businessFoundations).subscribe(data => {
                  this.businessFoundationsKey = data.$key;
                  formControls.businessFoundationsQ1.setValue(data.businessFoundationsQ1);
                  formControls.businessFoundationsQ2.setValue(data.businessFoundationsQ2);
                  this.loading.dismiss();
                })
              } else {
                this.isThisFirstTimeFlag = true;
                this.loading.dismiss();
              }
            });

          } else {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.log ("Current State: NOT Login");
          }
        });

      }

      saveForm(): void {
        let data = this.businessFoundationsForm.value;
        let dataToSave = {
          locationId: this.locationId,
          uid: this.userId,
          youTuberName: this.YouTuber.name,
          businessFoundationsQ1: data.businessFoundationsQ1,
          businessFoundationsQ2: data.businessFoundationsQ2,
        }
        console.log (data);
        if (this.isThisFirstTimeFlag) {
          this.userData.createBusinessFoundationsData(this.userId, dataToSave);
        } else {
          this.userData.updateBusinessFoundationsData(this.businessFoundationsKey, dataToSave);
        }
      }

    }
```

The 3 input fields has Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10). Here is the HTML:

```
    <form [formGroup]="businessFoundationsForm" (change)="saveForm()">
  <ion-item text-wrap>
    <ion-label floating>What additional revenue streams have the most growth potential for your channel?</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea fz-elastic formControlName="businessFoundationsQ1"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item text-wrap>
    <ion-label floating>What is one business challenge you have and what can you do to improve in this area?</ion-label>
    <ion-textarea fz-elastic formControlName="businessFoundationsQ2"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

The form is saved every time the input is changed by hitting my firebase server. But I want it to only save when ONE of the fields is validated. Also, if the field values are the same, I also do not want to call Firebase (the save operation). Basically, I need to minimize the database calling the action when it absolutely necessary without user click the stupid submit button. I am on Ionic 2 BTW. So let's say situations can be:

1. Input field first is typed, but not meet the validation - saveForm stop.
2. Input field first is typed, and meet the validation but field second is still empty - saveForm save (Autosave!!)
3. Input field second is typed, but not meet the validation and field first is not change - saveForm stop.
4. Input field second is typed, and meet the validation, but field first is empty - still saveForm save (AutoSave!!)
5. User edit field first but not meet the validation, field second does not change - saveForm stop.

I can not think of other situations. Any suggestion on how to build this with reactive / observerable reactive form?

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to value changes with 200 ms [debounce](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/debounceTime.ts) or more, so if user is not typing for 200 ms then subscribe will be called. And if form is valid do save

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public fb: FormBuilder, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public userData: UserData) {
    this.locationId = this.navParams.get('locationId');
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Please wait...'
    });

    this.loading.present();

    this.businessFoundationsForm = this.fb.group({
        businessFoundationsQ1: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
        businessFoundationsQ2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
    })

    this.businessFoundationsForm.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(200)
        .subscribe(() => {
            if (businessFoundationsForm.valid && businessFoundationsForm.dirty) {
                this.saveForm();
                businessFoundationsForm.reset()
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank for the quick response. Could you explain what is the autoSaveSubscriber and why the autoSaveSubscriber.unsubscribe()? Also, are you suggest I do not use (change)="saveForm()" in the template form level, but instead of putting the valueChanges inside the constructor and initialize immediately?

Comment: Actually, your solution call my database MORE than my original question solution. It call the database even the value is EXACTLY the same as the original value within the debounceTime - I set it 1000. It also call the database when the form is first initialized from empty value to load up the previous value from Firebase.  Also, it call the database every debounceTime interval - as before using Ionic, it only call when the input is NOT highlight anymore (user finished typing and close the keypad on their phone). So this is NOT a better solution, unfortunately.

Comment: @HughHou Hey, autosaveSubscruber was uncleanded code, when i started i had one idea but later did it better. Check my update in forms there is touched property which says if user modifles smth

Comment: @HughHou also i have added reset form to prevent saving already saved data

Comment: @HughHou check now, its just valid property https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html

Comment: So this still not working right. Since this line: this.businessFoundationsForm.invalid - the form won't save until Q2 is validated. So when user only working on Q1, the result won't be save . This defeat the autosave from feature entirely.

Comment: But you added validators how you want to save invalid data??

Comment: If you dont want to validate then just remove validation and check only if its touched or even better check for dirty

Comment: touched is when there was focus on field, dirty is when user changed smth

Comment: In autosave form. If one of the field is valid, it save that field. Other is not affected. If that make sense. But if that field become invalid, stop the saving function. Initially, only the first typing field has value, it should allow it to save. Later in edit, let say one of the field become invalid via editing, it should stop the saving. How autosave behave.